# php refactoring small function

Tags: php, if-statement, refactoring, echo

Is it possible to reduce this expression to one line?

```
    echo '<li>';
    echo $value['name'];
    if ($value['childs']) {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo $this->arrayToString($value['childs']);
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
```

For example:

```
echo '<li>' . $value['name'] // what to do if statement? ... ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It deffinitely is possible:

```
echo '<li>' . $value['name'] . ($value['childs'] ? '<ul>' . $this->arrayToString($value['childs']) . '</ul>' : '') . '</li>';
```

But I really do not recommend it. I will be much less readable. Maybe reather try to extract one part to another function like this:

```
function printItem($value)
{
    echo '<li>' . $value['name'] . $this->printItemChilds($value) . '</li>';
}

function printItemChilds($value)
{
    return $value['childs'] ? '<ul>' . $this->arrayToString($value['childs']) . '</ul>' : '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas! You really helped me.